# Angular's link function vs Angular 2's constructor

Tags: javascript, angular

Being new to `Angular2`, and its component architecture, I could understand that, Components are enhanced version of Angular's directives.

And when I look at the `constructor` which pertains to a particular I component that I tend to write, It more or less does the same work which the `link` function use to perform in `Angular 1.x` since the `link` function gets executed for each instance of directive so that each instance gets it’s own business-logic without affecting others.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3):

The `contructor` is called for each instance.

So `constructor`can be used, but it is better to use `ngOnInit` because it hooks into the Angular lifecycle

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Venomy, I would like to know whether both are same conceptually as it is doing the same job.

Comment: @DavidR They are conceptually the same but the time of execution is different. The `constructor` is a feature of the class itself, while `ngOnInit` is an Angular feature. Thus Angular has no control over the `constructor` and it is safer to use `ngOnInit` in case you have to execute code after component initialization for example. I hope this answers your question

Comment: I understand.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

While the `constructor` function of an Angular 2 Component and the `link` function of an AngularJS directive are called at similar times (During creation) I would not go as far as to say that they are conceptually the same.  A notable difference would be that within a `link` function of an AngularJS directive the HTML Element represented by the directive has already been created while in the `constructor` function of an Angular 2 `component` it has not.

As @Venomy has explained, `ngOnInit` is a better analogy to a `link` function as both are features of the framework.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Joe!